# "expected CPU tensor(got CUDA tensor)" error for PyTorch

Tags: python, model, inference, pytorch, tensor

In my inference code with Trained PyTorch model, What's wrong ?

There is an runtime error message: "expected CPU tensor(got CUDA tensor)"

---

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
#from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
from PIL import Image
import torchvision.models as models
import skimage.io
from torch.autograd import Variable as V
from torch.nn import functional as f
from torchvision import transforms as trn


# define image transformation
centre_crop = trn.Compose([
trn.ToPILImage(),
trn.Scale(256),
trn.CenterCrop(224),
trn.ToTensor(),
trn.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
])

filename=r'ed91.png'
img = skimage.io.imread(filename)

x = V(centre_crop(img).unsqueeze(0), volatile=True)

model = models.__dict__['resnet18']()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()

model = torch.load('mw_model0831.pth')
#model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

#best_prec1 = checkpoint['best_prec1']
logit = model(x)

print(logit)
print(len(logit))
h_x = f.softmax(logit).data.squeeze()
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the error is a mismatch between the model which is in `cuda`
and the variable `x` you are using as an input, which is a CPU tensor.

Try to add `.cuda()` to your variable so both match:

```
x = V(centre_crop(img).unsqueeze(0), volatile=True).cuda()
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is because the `model` is on GPU while your input image `x` is on CPU. You have to make sure that they are both on GPU or CPU.

Also, `model.cuda()` and `x.cuda()` behaves slightly differently: `model.cuda()` will put the `model` on GPU, but `x.cuda()` just return a new Variable on GPU, leaving the original `x` untouched. You have to assign the return value to `x` explicitly.

You can find a detailed discussion [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/1472).